# Design Interview - Car Reservation System

Tags: oop

A Car Reservation System is a very popular question in Software Development Interviews. 
I designed the following ER structure/OOP structure when I was asked this:

Car class/table has Car Id#, Type (Compact, Standard, etc), Make, Model
Customer has Customer Id#, etc
Reservation is an associative table storing Car Id#, Customer Id# and Date for which the car is reserved. For the sake of simplicity we can assume that car can be reserved only in chunks of days.

Here's the tricky part where I floundered - 
What happens when a customer 1 reserves a compact car having Id Car 3 on July 27. What happens if Car 3 is totaled on July 24. Other compact cars are available, however between July 24 and 27 they all get taken. So when Customer 1 arrives on July 27, he ultimately has no car.

The flaw I think is in the way Car and Customer are coupled in the Reservations table. Is there any better way to model this relationship and also the regular use cases such find an available car for a particular date, reserve it for that date etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can add another `boolean` field to `Car` called `Working`.
If `Car 3` is totaled then

- set `Working` to `false`.
- search for it in `Reservation`.
- if it's there, then search for another car of that type in `Car`.
- if found then replace this car with the other car in `Reservation`.
- else call the customer.

Comment: Then the question comes - at what point do we want to check whether the Car is working? A nightly script that runs and replaces all the totaled/damaged cars with other equivalent working ones?

Comment: You chose to use the Entity-Relation model. A `Car` and a `Customer` are definitely entities. `Reservation` is definitely a relation between a `Car` and a `Customer`. Whether a `Car` is totaled/damaged is definitely a `property` of the entity `Car`. This design is true to the Entity-Relation model principles and should withstand the different use cases that are thrown at it. Including your last question.